# Including variables after filtering selecting only minimum values in SQL?

Tags: sql, filter, datatable, min

I am working with a twin dataset and would like to create a table with the Subject ID (Subject) and twin pair ID (twpair) for the twins with the lower (or one of the twins if the values are equal) lifetime total of marijuana use (MJ1a).

A portion of my table looks like this:

| Subject | twpair | MJ1a |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 156 | 345 | 10 |
| 157 | 345 | 7 |
| 158 | 346 | 20 |
| 159 | 346 | 3 |
| 160 | 347 | 4 |
| 161 | 347 | 4 |

I'm hoping to create a table with only the twins that have the lower amount of marijuana use which would look like this:

| Subject | twpair | MJ1a |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 157 | 345 | 7 |
| 159 | 346 | 3 |
| 161 | 347 | 4 |

This is the SQL code I have so far:

```
proc sql; 
create table one_twin as 
select twpair,min(MJ1a) as minUse, Subject 
from twins_deviation
group by twpair;
```

Unfortunately this ends up causing all of the subjects to be remerged back in the dataset. If I don't include the Subject portion I get the correct values for twpair and MJ1a but not the Subject IDs.

How do I filter the dataset to only include those with the minimum values while also including variables of interest like Subject ID? Note that if two pairs of twins have the SAME value I would like to select one but it doesn't matter which I select. Any tips would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: Order by `MJ1a desc` and take first 3 rows. Exact syntax depends on your DB product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should give you the desired result.

`select a.subject,a.twpair,a.MJ1a from twins_deviation a join (select twpair,min(mj1a) as mj1a from twins_deviation group by twpair)b on a.twpair=b.twpair and a.mj1a=b.mj1a`

If your DB supports analytic/window functions ,the same can be accomplished using a rank function ,solution given below.

EDIT1:to handle same values for mj1a

`select subject,twpair,mj1a from(select subject,twpair,mj1a ,row_number() over(partition by twpair order by mj1a) as rnk from twins_deviation)out1 where rnk=1;`

EDIT2:Updated solution 1 to include only one twin.

`select min(subject) as subject,twpair,mj1a from(select a.subject as subject ,a.twpair as twpair,a.MJ1a as MJ1a from twins_deviation a join (select twpair,min(mj1a) as mj1a from twins_deviation group by twpair)b on a.twpair=b.twpair and a.mj1a=b.mj1a)out1 group by twpair,MJ1a;`

Comment: I'm so sorry for not making my question more clear. Is it possible to edit this code to make it drop one of the two twins if the values for MJ1a are equal? I clarified my question after using your code because I realize this will drop the twins with higher levels of use but keeps both if their values are the same. I'm hoping to select only one twin per pair

Comment: np,sorry for not considering that scenario.I have updated the second solution to give exactly one twin per pair.Instead of rank it is using rownumber.I'll check how to tweak the first solution as well.

Comment: I am getting a syntax error between the row_number() over(partition by portion. It says: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: !, !!, &, *, **, +, ',', -, /, <... 
Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: which DB you are trying to run the query on?Need to check if this is supported

Comment: I am doing this in SAS, so I'm not sure if this is supported. Is there a way for me to modify the first option that does not require a software supporting these functions?

Comment: Added the updated query.Not the most elegant solution to the problem.I'm sure there should be some better ways to solve it.Nothing is clicking as of now :) will try to figure out if there is any other option.